# Jackson XML Deserializing XML to POJO from 2nd Level

Tags: java, xml, jackson-dataformat-xml

hopefully this is not too much of a noob question.  I am trying to deserialise an XML to a POJO from the 2nd level of the XML, but after searching and trying many answers to other questions similar to this, I am still struggling to find something for this level.

The XML (which is provided and I cannot change), comes through similar to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:InputRequest xmlns:ns0="OW">
    <ns0:FMan>
        <ns0:CInc>
            <ns0:Act>Sample</ns0:Act>
            <ns0:Op>Sample</ns0:Op>
            <ns0:Int>AppInt</ns0:Int>
        </ns0:CInc>
    </ns0:FMan>
</ns0:InputRequest>
```

I only need to deserialise the CInc (there will only ever be one) into my POJO, which looks similar to

```
public class CInc extends InputRequest {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "ns0", localName = "Act")
    private String action;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "ns0", localName = "Op")
    private String operation;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "ns0", localName = "Int")
    private String intName;

    // Usual Getters, Setters, etc

}
```

I am extending an abstract top level class, as follows

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(namespace = "ns0", localName = "InputRequest")
public class InputRequest { }
```

MY Java Code looks similar to

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
CInc cInc = xmlMapper.readValue(content, CInc.class);
```

This fails because of the missing FMan element.

From another answer, I tried disabling FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES like this

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
CInc cInc = xmlMapper.readValue(content, CInc.class);
```

This takes away the failure, but all the values in the POJO are null.

I have also tried putting another abstract class for the 'FMan' element that extends the 'InputRequest' and then changing CInc to extend FMan, I.e.

```
public class FMan extends InputRequest {
...
```

and

```
public class CInc extends FMan {
...
```

But this doesn't help at all.  I feel the answer is something silly I am missing, but I am really struggling to get the answer to this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know it used Jackson, must be serialized, in other words, extend serialize and have a  private serial version ID property, the same is true to the Super Class .

```
 public class CInc extends InputRequest,serialize {
    private final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    *****
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with SimpleXml. Add this POJO;

```
@XmlName("ns0:CInc")
public class Cinc {
    @XmlName("ns0:Act")
    public String act;
    @XmlName("ns0:Op")
    public String op;
    @XmlName("ns0:Int")
    public String Int;
}
```

Next the code to deserialize and print the output:

```
public static void main(final String... args) throws InvalidXPath, IOException {
    final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
    final Cinc c = simple.fromXml(xml, "ns0:InputRequest/ns0:FMan/ns0:CInc", Cinc.class);
    System.out.println(c.act + " - " + c.op + " - " + c.Int);
}
```

This will print:

```
Sample - Sample - AppInt
```

SimpleXml is in maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```